# Offsets topic retention vs Topic retention

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have a Topic with a retention of 7 days, with the offsets retention set to 1 day I can end up int he situation where by consumer group, if re-started after 2 days, would reprocess the messages because the offset has expired. (As per: https://anshita-singh.medium.com/kafka-message-retention-v-s-committed-offset-retention-c2359e3f9c5b)

What happens the other way around? If I have a Topic retention of 1 day and offset retention of 7 days, when the Kafka consumer starts, it wants to read from a position that doesn't yet exist. Does Kafka gracefully handle this?...or will, when publishing messages to the topic, will they not be read by the consumer because its position is far into the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a brand new consumer group **or** when an out of bounds offset is requested, then the `auto.offset.reset` property will take affect. By default, it'll start consuming from the end of the topic.

However, "yet" doesn't really make sense. The offsets are constantly increasing. You'd have to explicitly request one greater than what exists

Comment: `or when an out of bounds offset is requested` - nice way to describe it. This answers my question - thanks.